# Access namespace in parent file from included child file (php)

Tags: php, namespaces

I am pretty new to PHP namespaces projects. I am trying to setup a simple project. Let's say I have a file **header.php**. At the top of the file I have this code:

```
use Src\Myclass;
```

In my **header.php** I am able to call

```
new Myclass()
```

Now I have a file called **index.php**. I include **header.php** in this file:

```
include 'header.php'
```

Since header.php already has *'use Src\MyClass'*, why can't I call **new MyClass()** from the **index.php** file?

If I add the use statement to the index.php file as well, I can call new MyClass() again, but it seems redundant because I already included the use statement in the included header.php?

And the exact same issue applies when declaring the use in a parent file, then including child files. The child files will not be able to access the class that's included with the use statement in the parent file.

So, if I have a **index.php** file which call 10 subfiles (for example) **menu.php**, **footer.php**, **partial-1.php**, etc. Do I need to add the use statement to all these subfiles? (it seems like it from my testing) why can't I access the class via the use statement in the parent file? Just like I normally would be able to access variables defined in the parent class.

I have a feeling there must be a better/cleaner way to accessing a class in all subfiles, instead of having to add

```
use Src\Myclass;
```

To each individual subfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces, that's `namespace` *and* `use` declarations, only apply to the file they're in. They do not implicitly get applied to other included or including files.

`namespace` and `use` are literally just syntax helpers for *names of things.* You *could* be writing `class Src_MyClass` and `new Src_MyClass` every time; that was the old way of "namespacing" before namespace support existed in PHP. All `namespace` does is to implicitly prepend that namespace before every relevant name in the file, and all `use` does is to let you implicitly refer to namespaced names by a shorter name inside the file.

If these rules would implicitly be applied globally across files, it would become rather impossible to track and understand what name actually refers to what. So this aliasing and namespacing is localised to each individual file.

Comment: Ok, that kind of makes sense. But I use composer autoload, and I thought that adding 'use Src\MyClass' would be equivalent to require_once(src\myclass.php). But it isn't, right? Because if it was, it would make it possible for me to access the tradingplatform class in included subfiles I guess..

Is it correct that the use is just like a kind of pointer to a certain file, and the actual require/include of the PHP class is only done when I call 'new MyClass()'

Comment: Yes, `use` has absolutely nothing to do with `require`. That is done through the autoload mechanism, and that kicks in regardless of whether  you use `use` or not.

Comment: Ok, I'm almost there I think. But what exactly triggers the actual class loading in case of this autoload mechamism? Is just every class within a namespace autoloaded, or is calling the classname the trigger? (sorry it's all new to me..)

Comment: The first time the class definition is *necessary* and PHP can't find the class is when the autoloader is asked to load the class. Things like `use Foo\Bar` and `Bar::class` do *not* necessitate to have the class details loaded; but `new Bar` or `class Baz extends Bar` *do*.